# Program with multiple threads, not printing expected output

Tags: c++, linux, pthreads, shared-memory

I'm using Ubuntu 12 and when I compile the code on the terminal I use:
    `$ g++ -o ./myProgram ./main.cpp`, then
    `$ ./myProgram`
I don't get any errors or warnings, but it doesn't print anything outside of the main function.

For some reason it seems that the pthread_creat command in the main function is not working.

This is my program code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

using namespace std;

pthread_mutex_t jobMutex;
key_t key = 5678;
#define SHMSZ 27

int shmid;

class Job {
public:
int speed, pleasant, easy;

//initialization, constructor, destructor

Job() {
}

Job(int new_s, int new_p, int new_e) {
    speed = new_s;
    pleasant = new_p;
    easy = new_e;
}

~Job() {
}
};

struct sh_data {
Job j_list[10]; //array of jobs on bulletin board
int clock;
int kid_count;
} *shared, *update;

class Child {
private:
int pid;
int j_pref;
Job* j_list;
int clock;
int score;

public:

Child() {
} //constructor

void read_mem() {
    sh_data* data;

    if ((shmid = shmget(key, SHMSZ, 0666)) < 0) {
        cerr << "\tshmget\n";
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    pthread_mutex_lock(&jobMutex);

    if ((data = (sh_data *) shmat(shmid, NULL, 0)) == (sh_data *) -1) {
        cerr << "\tshmat\n";
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    j_list = data->j_list;
    clock = data->clock;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&jobMutex);
}

void write_mem(int index) {
    sh_data* data;

    if ((shmid = shmget(key, SHMSZ, 0666)) < 0) {
        cerr << "\tshmget\n";
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    pthread_mutex_lock(&jobMutex);

    if ((data = (sh_data *) shmat(shmid, NULL, 0)) == (sh_data *) -1) {
        cerr << "\tshmat\n";
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    data->j_list[index].speed = 0;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&jobMutex);
}

//all preference functions

void pref_quick() {
    cout << "Child prefers a quick job \n";
    read_mem();

    while (clock < 20) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&jobMutex);
        read_mem();

        int cur_job;
        int speed = j_list[0].speed;

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            if (j_list[i].speed < speed && j_list[i].speed > 0) {
                cur_job = i;
                speed = j_list[i].speed;
            }
        }

        cout << "Child " << pid << " selected job " << cur_job << " with speed " << speed << "\n";

        //calculate total score so far
        score += j_list[cur_job].speed + j_list[cur_job].pleasant + j_list[cur_job].easy;

        write_mem(cur_job);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&jobMutex);
        sleep(j_list[cur_job].speed);
    }
}

void pref_profit() {
    cout << "Child prefers a job with highest profit \n";\
    read_mem();

    while (clock < 20) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&jobMutex);
        read_mem();

        int cur_job;
        int profit = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            if (j_list[i].speed + j_list[i].pleasant + j_list[i].easy > profit) {
                cur_job = i;
                profit = j_list[i].speed + j_list[i].pleasant + j_list[i].easy;
            }
        }

        cout << "Child " << pid << " selected job " << cur_job << " with profit " << profit << "\n";

        //calculate total score so far
        score += profit;

        write_mem(cur_job);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&jobMutex);
        sleep(j_list[cur_job].speed);
    }
}

void pref_simple() {
    cout << "Child prefers a simple job \n";
    read_mem();

    while (clock < 20) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&jobMutex);
        read_mem();

        int cur_job;
        int ease = j_list[0].easy;

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            if (j_list[i].easy < ease) {
                cur_job = i;
                ease = j_list[i].easy;
            }
        }

        cout << "Child " << pid << " selected job " << cur_job << " with ease " << ease << "\n";

        //calculate total score so far
        score += j_list[cur_job].speed + j_list[cur_job].pleasant + j_list[cur_job].easy;

        write_mem(cur_job);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&jobMutex);
        sleep(j_list[cur_job].speed);
    }
}

void pref_clean() {
    cout << "Child prefers a clean job \n";
    read_mem();

    while (clock < 20) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&jobMutex);
        read_mem();

        int cur_job;
        int clean = j_list[0].pleasant;

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            if (j_list[i].pleasant < clean) {
                cur_job = i;
                clean = j_list[i].pleasant;
            }
        }

        cout << "Child " << pid << " selected job " << cur_job << " with cleanliness " << clean << "\n";

        //calculate total score so far
        score += j_list[cur_job].speed + j_list[cur_job].pleasant + j_list[cur_job].easy;

        write_mem(cur_job);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&jobMutex);
        sleep(j_list[cur_job].speed);
    }
}

void* worker() {
    sh_data* data;

    if ((shmid = shmget(key, SHMSZ, 0666)) < 0) {
        cerr << "\tshmget\n";
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    pthread_mutex_lock(&jobMutex);

    if ((data = (sh_data *) shmat(shmid, NULL, 0)) == (sh_data *) -1) {
        cerr << "\tshmat\n";
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    j_list = data->j_list;
    pid = data->kid_count;
    j_pref = rand() % 4;
    data->kid_count++;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&jobMutex);

    cout << "Job Preference for Child " << pid << " is: " << j_pref << "\n";

    //select a job preference
    switch (j_pref) {
        case 0: //fastest job
            cout << "Selecting quickest job\n";
            pref_quick();
            break;
        case 1: //cleanest job
            cout << "Selecting the most pleasant job\n";
            pref_clean();
            break;
        case 2: //simplest job
            cout << "Selecting the most simple job\n";
            pref_simple();
            break;
        case 3: //most profitable job
            cout << "Selecting the most profitable job\n";
            pref_profit();
            break;
        default: //quickest job by default
            cout << "Selecting quickest job\n";
            pref_quick();
            break;
    }
}

~Child() { //destructor
}

//static helper function to get rid of hidden "this" parameter from pthread_create

static void *Child_helper(void *context) {
    cout << "\tChild helper function called\n";
    return ((Child *) context)->worker();
}
};

class Mom {
private:
Job j_list[10]; //unending list of 10 jobs
int clock;
pthread_t child_id[4]; //thread ids for each child

public:
//create job with random speed, pleasant, easy values

Job newJob() {
    int rand_val[3];

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        rand_val[i] = rand() % 5 + 1;
    }

    return Job(rand_val[0], rand_val[1], rand_val[2]);
}

void read_mem() {
    sh_data* data;

    if ((shmid = shmget(key, SHMSZ, 0666)) < 0) {
        cerr << "\tshmget\n";
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    pthread_mutex_lock(&jobMutex);

    if ((data = (sh_data *) shmat(shmid, NULL, 0)) == (sh_data *) -1) {
        cerr << "\tshmat\n";
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        j_list[i] = data->j_list[i];
    }

    clock = data->clock;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&jobMutex);
}

void write_mem(Job new_job, int index, int clock) {
    sh_data* data;

    if ((shmid = shmget(key, SHMSZ, 0666)) < 0) {
        cerr << "\tshmget\n";
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    pthread_mutex_lock(&jobMutex);

    if ((data = (sh_data *) shmat(shmid, NULL, 0)) == (sh_data *) -1) {
        cerr << "\tshmat\n";
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    data->j_list[index] = new_job;
    data->clock = clock;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&jobMutex);
}

void write_mem(int clock) {
    sh_data* data;

    if ((shmid = shmget(key, SHMSZ, 0666)) < 0) {
        cerr << "\tshmget\n";
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    pthread_mutex_lock(&jobMutex);

    if ((data = (sh_data *) shmat(shmid, NULL, 0)) == (sh_data *) -1) {
        cerr << "\tshmat\n";
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    data->clock = clock;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&jobMutex);
}

//chores() creates shared memory, checks checks and update shared memory, and creates children

void* chores() {
    cout << "\tChores function called\n";

    shmid = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, 1, IPC_CREAT);
    cout << "\tValue of shmid: " << shmid << "\n";

    if (shmid == -1) {
        shmid = shmget(key, sizeof (sh_data), IPC_CREAT);

        if (-1 == shmid) {
            cout << "\tCould not get shmid\n";
        } else {
            pthread_mutex_lock(&jobMutex);

            //system chooses the address
            shared = (sh_data *) shmat(shmid, 0, 0);
            update = shared;

            pthread_mutex_unlock(&jobMutex);
        }
    } else {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&jobMutex);

        cout << "Mom created job list!\n";

        //system chooses the address
        shared = (sh_data *) shmat(shmid, (void*) 0, 0);
        update = shared;
        update->kid_count = 0;

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&jobMutex);
    }

    sh_data* data;

    Child * child[4];

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        cout << "~~Thread created for Child " << i + 1 << "\n";
        child[i] = new Child();

        //calls worker function from Child class
        pthread_create(&child_id[i], NULL, &Child::Child_helper, child[i]);
    }

    while (clock < 20) {
        cout << "\tMom will sleep for 2 units\n";
        sleep(2);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&jobMutex);
        read_mem();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            if (j_list[i].speed == 0) {
                cout << "Mommy added a new job to the bulletin board!!\n";
                j_list[i] = newJob();
                write_mem(j_list[i], i, clock);
            }
        }

        clock += 2;
        write_mem(clock);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&jobMutex);
        cout << "Mom says time is now: " << clock << "\n";
    }

    payup();
}

void payup() {
    int max, winner;

    max = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        //wait for all children to finish tasks
        int* status = 0;
        pthread_join(child_id[i], (void**) status);
        cout << "Child " << i << " completes tasks that earned him/her " << *status << " points!\n";
        if (max < *status) {
            max = *status;
            winner = i;
        }
    }

    cout << "The winner is child " << winner << ", with " << max << " points!\n";
}

Job* get_jlist() {
    return j_list;
}

int get_time() {
    return clock;
}

//static helper function to get rid of hidden "this" parameter from pthread_create

static void *Mom_helper(void *context) {
    cout << "\tHelper function called\n";
    return ((Mom *) context)->chores();
}

//initialization, constructor, destructor

Mom() {
    srand(time(NULL));
}

~Mom() {
}
};

int main() {
cout << "Program 7: Chores using Threads\n\n";

pthread_t threads;
pthread_mutex_init(&jobMutex, NULL);

//instantiate mom class and call chores()
Mom* mommy = new Mom();
cout << "~~Made Mom\n";

//calls chores function from Mom class
pthread_create(&threads, NULL, &Mom::Mom_helper, mommy);
cout << "~~Created threads\n";

pthread_mutex_destroy(&jobMutex);
cout << "~~Destroyed threads\n";

return 0;
}
```

Am I doing something wrong, I've been looking all over and comparing my code to others and it seems to be correct. But it is not working. Can anyone shed some light on this situation?

Comment: It would help to have a smaller example demonstrating the problem.

Comment: 486 lines of code. Seriously?

Comment: That's nearly 500 lines of code.  You are much more likely to get a response if you simplify this down into a small program that exhibits the problem.  Also, try compiling with `-Wall`.  The compile command that you listed doesn't enable any warnings.

Comment: a demo app which will effectively show the problem would be nice. have you tried to run it under gdb? $gdb info threads is pretty useful.

Comment: by the way i did not forget to have the -lpthread option in my command... i just forgot to write it up top just now

Comment: well, it's really just the pthread_creat in the main function to the Mom class that I'm having a problem with... if I can get that to work, I;m sure I'll be able to figure out the rest

Comment: It is a painfully obvious that this is a homework assignment, which is fine, but you didn't even take the time to try and figure out what the problem was before dumping all you code on the internet for someone else to fix. This site is for help, not doing all the work for you. -.-

Comment: I just tried using the gdb command and ran the program, when it went through it called the helper function. And sometimes it calls the chores function. But even when it does it stops working after it get the shmid.

Answer (score 5):

That's a lot of code to read but you don't seem to be waiting for the thread. Your main thread calls `pthread_create` and (likely) exits the process before the new thread has a chance to run.

You'll probably want to call [`pthread_join`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/pthread_join.3.html), somewhere before `pthread_mutex_destroy`.

```
pthread_create(&threads, ...);
pthread_join(threads, zahir);
```

Comment: is correct. You need a pthread_join() to wait on the launched thread to return or some sort of infinite loop after the thread is launched.  That really is a good place to stick useful stuff that runs and waits, runs and waits.